# show div instead of TextBox c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, textbox

I have 1 TextBox and 1 Button. I want to display 5 `div`, if user enter 5 in the textbox and clicked the button for example.

I have this but I don't know how to make it to div

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int NumberOfTextBoxes = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox_UserEntry.Text);
    for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfTextBoxes; i++)
    {
        TextBox tb = new TextBox();
        tb.ID = "tb" + Convert.ToInt32(i + 1);
        Panel1.Controls.Add(tb);
    }
}
```

can you help me to change

```
TextBox tb = new TextBox();
tb.ID = "tb" + Convert.ToInt32(i + 1);
Panel1.Controls.Add(tb);
```

to `div`

```
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox_UserEntry" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" />
                <asp:Panel ID="ParentPanel" runat="server">
                </asp:Panel>
```

**div**

```
                <div id="divOccupantProfile">

                <asp:Label ID="OPfamilyname" runat="server" Text="Family Name"></asp:Label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="textOPfamilyname" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />

                <asp:Label ID="OPfirstname" runat="server" Text="First Name"></asp:Label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="textOPfirstname" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />

                <asp:Label ID="OPmiddlename" runat="server" Text="Middle Name"></asp:Label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="textOPmiddlename" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />

                <asp:Label ID="OPmaritalstatus" runat="server" Text="Marital Status"></asp:Label>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlOPmaritalstatus" runat="server" >
                    <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Married</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Single</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Divorced</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList><br />

                <asp:Label ID="OPoccupation" runat="server" Text="Occupation"></asp:Label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="textOPoccupation" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />

                <asp:Label ID="OPrelationship" runat="server" Text="Relationship"></asp:Label>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlOPrelationship" runat="server" >
                    <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Wife</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Daughter</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Son</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Father</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Mother</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>House helper</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Driver</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>

                </div>
```

Comment: I hope that is ASP.NET WebForms?

Comment: yes @SergeyBerezovskiy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Panel` for this purpose. It renders as `Div`.

```
int NumberOfDiv = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox_UserEntry.Text);
for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfDiv; i++)
{
    Panel pnl = new Panel();
    pnl.ID = "pnl" + Convert.ToInt32(i + 1);
    ParentPanel.Controls.Add(pnl);
}
```

Comment: Rename your `Panel1` to `ParentPanel` or replace it with `Panel1`

Comment: Its not working is not a good explanation. explain the issue and update your code accordingly.

Comment: `{
                Panel pnl = new Panel();
                pnl.ID = "divOccupantProfile" + Convert.ToInt32(i + 1);
                ParentPanel.Controls.Add(pnl);
            }`